# Google Play: Testing in-app-purchases using settings from different country?

Tags: react-native, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, android-inapp-purchase

I'm testing my React Native app by setting up a closed beta testing track on the Google Play console. The main thing I'm testing is in-app-purchases (IAPs) whose prices vary depending on region, so I want to be able to simulate Canadian and American accounts. I tried changing the region in the Google Play app settings, but can't change the country. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 0):

it is not easy to test this, but the way to do this is by creating two new google accounts one for Canada and one for US and use a VPN to totally simulate users from these countries.